# Add columns to Pandas dataframe based on another dataframe and set values to zero

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Pandas dataframes, as shown below:

```
import pandas as pd
main_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'day1': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'day2': [2, 1, 3, 4],
    'day3': [3, 1, 2, 5],
    'day4': [2, 1, 3, 5],
    'day5': [4, 1, 2, 3],
    'day6': [5, 3, 4, 2]}, index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'day1': [0, 1, 0],
    'day3': [0, 0, 1]
})
```

I want to add the columns in main_df to df and set their values to 0. My expected output is:

```
df
    day1  day2  day3  day4  day5 day6
0    0      0    0      0    0     0
1    1      0    0      0    0     0
2    0      0    1      0    0     0
```

I can do this the following way in a loop:

```
cols_to_add = main_df.columns[~main_df.columns.isin(df.columns)]
for c in cols_to_add:
    df[c] = 0
```

Is there a way I do it without looping? Note that the indices of both dataframes are different.

Comment: Please show your expected output and share your attempt at solving this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `dict` and `assign`:

```
cols_to_add = main_df.columns[~main_df.columns.isin(df.columns)]
d = dict.fromkeys(cols_to_add, 0)
df.assign(**d)
```

Or

```
pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(columns = cols_to_add)]).fillna(0)
```

---

```
   day1     day3    day2    day4    day5    day6
0   0       0       0       0       0       0
1   1       0       0       0       0       0
2   0       1       0       0       0       0
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use `df.reindex(columns=[x])` and `join` outcome to `df`

`x` in this instance is the column difference between `main_df` and `df`

```
df.join(df.reindex(columns=list(main_df.columns.difference(df.columns)))).fillna(0)

  day1     day3    day2    day4    day5    day6
0   0       0       0       0       0       0
1   1       0       0       0       0       0
2   0       1       0       0       0       0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do

```
df[cols_to_add] = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols_to_add, index=df.index).fillna(0)
```

DataFrame slices accept compatible DataFrames as values

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# 1 - List comprehension
col_to_add = [col for col in main_df.columns if col not in df.columns]
# 2 - Create values to add using pd.DataFrame constructor and numpy
zero_vals_df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.zeros((3,len(col_to_add)),dtype=int),columns=col_to_add,index=df.index)
# 3 - Join DataFrames to obtain the desired result
df = pd.concat([df,zero_vals_df],axis=1)
```

On my machine, using `%%timeit` magic cell I got the following performances:

429 µs ± 3.37 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

Note that this method requires you to add `numpy` as a dependency.